# How to export selenium WebDriver to runnable jar file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, runnable-jar

I try to make an exe file or something that could just open and work on my desktop. It works in Eclipse when I click run. I try to export it as a runnable jar file in Eclipse but it does not work. I guess it maybe the library or chromedriver path problem. Has someone successfully done this before?

```
package webdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver" );
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot-eclipse-project]

Comment: Use IntelliJ instead of Eclipse and then make a gradle project. This allows you to create a 'fat jar' (https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar) which can include all your sources

Comment: Hi james,  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the download link that will give you the jar file :
https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

download them and then in the project create a folder with name : lib
and add the jar files inside

Comment: I guess you still need to add it in the project structure in your eclipse project, or do you?

Comment: yes add it as an external jar in the libraries section